# unused arguments error occurs in response

Tags: r

Upon runing this code,

```
Attrition_edufield <- myds %>%
select(Attrition, EducationField) %>%
group_by(Attrition, EducationField) %>%
summarize(count = n())
```

I get response with

`Error in select(., Attrition, EducationField) : 
  unused arguments (Attrition, EducationField)`

Any idea why this occurs?

Comment: Please make your example reproducible. Also please check your post before submitting.

Comment: Roman is talking about [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `dplyr`'s `select`; however it appears that you have loaded another package that also defines a `select` function after loading `dplyr` and thus masking the one from `dplyr`.

Restart your R session, and load all the packages you use, while keeping an eye out for messages.

Try specifying the namescope by calling

```
Attrition_edufield <- myds %>%
  dplyr::select(Attrition, EducationField) %>%  # that's dplyr with two colons in front
  group_by(Attrition, EducationField) %>%
  summarize(count = n())
```

As an alternative, check that your variable `myds` is a data.frame (or related structure) and contains the columns you are trying to select.

Answer (score 0):

Some packages 'mask' certain objects from other packages. For instance if you call library(dplyr) then library(clusterSim) you'll get a message: 'The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’: select'. There may be another way to get around it but at first you may want to run your dplyr commands and then call the other packages which mess with it.